# Subir archivos de input files individuales (con nombres iguales) utilizando Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, ajax, formdata

Buen día, me estoy rompiendo la cabeza con un problema que tengo al intentar subir archivos a un directorio. El problema en si es poder obtener los archivos de cada uno de los input files que se generan dinámicamente (que tienen todos el mismo nombre) y adjuntarlos usando form data y enviarlos por Ajax. Mi código en cuestión es este:

**Archivo HTML:**

```
<form name="MiForm" id="MiForm" method="post" action="">
  <div class="float-left">
     <input class="form-control" type="file" name="miarchivo[]" required/>
     <input class="form-control" type="file" name="miarchivo[]" required/>
     <input class="form-control" type="file" name="miarchivo[]" required/>
     <input class="form-control" type="file" name="miarchivo[]" required/>
  </div>
</form>

<input type="button" value="Cargar Archivo" onclick="cargarArchivo()">
```

**Archivo Javascript:**

function cargarArchivo() {

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('miarchivo', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
                             
$.ajax({
    url: 'carga.php',  
    dataType: 'text',  
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,                         
    type: 'post',
    success: function(php_script_response){
        alert(php_script_response); 
    }
});
```

}

**Archivo PHP:**

```
<?php

    if($_FILES["miarchivo"]){

        foreach($_FILES["miarchivo"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

            if($_FILES["miarchivo"]["name"][$key]){

                $archivonombre = $_FILES["miarchivo"]["name"][$key]; 
                $fuente = $_FILES["miarchivo"]["tmp_name"][$key]; 
                
                $carpeta = 'archivos/';                
                $dir=opendir($carpeta);
                
                if(move_uploaded_file($fuente, $carpeta.'/'.$archivonombre)){   
                    echo "El archivo $archivonombre se ha cargado de forma correcta.<br>";
                }
                else{   
                    echo "Se ha producido un error, intentelo de nuevo.<br>";
                }
                closedir($dir); 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Se les agradece el apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Estás cargando solo el archivo del primer campo encontrado:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('miarchivo', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Tal vez deberías [hacer un ciclo](https://api.jquery.com/each/) y, de preferencia, declara las variables con `let`:

```
let form_data = new FormData();
// Recorres con un ciclo todos los archivos, por nombre
$('input[name="miarchivo[]"]').each((index, file) => {
    // Agregar cada archivo
    form_data.append('miarchivo[]', $(file)[0].files[0]);
});
```

O, todavía más simple, crea el objeto `FormData` con el formulario y todos los campos se agregarán automáticamente:

```
let form_data = new FormData($('MiForm')[0]);
// No es necesario realizar pasos adicionales
```